# What difference does changing a comma to a semicolon make?

Tags: conditionals

This is a "fill the blank" multiple choice exercise:

> 17. ........... return my money back, I will give you the loan papers.
>     a. Today you b. The day you c. On you. d You
> 18. ........... return my money back; I will give you the loan papers.
>     a. Today you are b. The day you c. On you. d You

[image]

what does a semicolon change in the sentence?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. We generally expect the people to research their questions before posting them here. That includes using the search box at the top of this page. After trying that, if you are still confused, please edit your question to explain that part that confuses you.

Comment: Please also enter text instead of linking to an image. The database cannot analyze an image, and we want all questions and answers to be searchable.

Comment: You will find lots of useful information if you google **punctuation** and/or **semicolons**.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELL!!! Firstly, just like others have said in the comments, please enter text instead of image, but I see that someone already helped you to edit it, so this problem is solved. Secondly, if you could kindly read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article about how to write a good question, you can find "search and research" in the first second. Please search for information online, especially on this site, to avoid your question being marked as duplicate. After doing some research, you can edit your post and include them in your question and explain what sti

Comment: Where is this question from?  "*Return* something *back*" does not sound fluent, because *return* already means "give back".

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon *joins* two sentences with related meaning.

So in (18) you need to choose an option that will make "........ return my money back" a complete sentence, and not a subordinate phrase.

But in (17) A comma separates elements in a single sentence, to indicate phrasing. You need to choose an option that will create a sensible introductory phrase.

But note that "return (something) back" is not idiomatic.  The word "return" already means "...back". You should expect that there are other mistakes in the test.

Comment: so no.18 would be The day you?  what about 17? thank you ❤️

Comment: For 18 you need to make a complete grammatical sentence.  Is "The day you return my money back"   a complete and grammatical sentence with a subject  and a verb?  For 17 you need an introductory phrase.  This could be an adverbial giving the time, location or manner (etc) of the main clause.

Comment: @MariamAyman: I agree with James; this exercise was **NOT** designed by a person who speaks/writes proper English. So unfortunately the two questions you asked about are simply wrong and do not have any right answer. We can guess the 'official answer', but that would be Psychology rather than English...